# Why constructor of A object is executed even though we change it manually to another constructor while creating objects using new keyword?

Tags: javascript, object

```
function Animal() { console.log("Animal")}
function Bird() { console.log("Bird")}
function Dog() { console.log("Dog")}

Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);


 duck = new Bird();
 beagle = new Dog();
```

In the above code - we inherit Bird and Dog from Animal.
Their prototype will be animal. So by Default **Bird.constructor** will be pointing to Animal constructor.

When new Bird() is executed. I expect "Animal to be logged on console" but Bird is logged. Since the constructor is Animal. Animal constructor should be executed right? Correct my understanding

Comment: your assertions are not correct.

Comment: Can you tell me the reasons @Pointy

Comment: yes working on it :)

Comment: prototype and constructor are different things.

Comment: "*When `new Bird()` is executed I expect "Animal" to be logged on console*" - Why? `Bird` is defined as `function Bird() { console.log("Bird") }` so that's what you get when calling it.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing inheritance with constructor calls. When you say:

```
duck = new Bird();
```

you are making an **explicit** call to the `Bird` constructor function so, of course, `Bird` will fire.

---

While `Object.create()` is a handy way of causing one object to inherit from another, you still have to manually set up the constructor chain. A good way to understand this is when both constructors take arguments (shown below).

See comments inline:

```js
function Animal(gender) {
  // The argument allows the instance property to initialize.
  // gender will be a property of Animal and will be inherited
  // by anything that inherits from Animal later. But, that
  // doesn't change the fact that the Animal constructor
  // must be called and passed the gender for the Animal
  // to be properly initialized.
  this.gender = gender;
  
  // Get the caller of this function (non-standard technique - just used for demo).
  // If the caller is null, it means that Animal was called directly. If not,
  // we can get the name of the calling function:
  var caller = Animal.caller ? Animal.caller.name : "Animal";
  
  // Report of newly constructed Animal
  console.log("Animal is a " + this.gender + ". (called by: " + caller + ")");
}


function Bird(gender, canFly) {   
  // Because a bird inherits from an Animal, you have
  // to manually ensure that when a new Bird is created
  // the Animal constructor gets called. You can see 
  // why this is necessary as we have a situation where
  // the prototype's constructor is expecting an argument
  // that we've received when the constructor of the 
  // derived object was called. We certainly don't want
  // to have to rewrite the code that sets the gender, so
  // we call the prototype's constructor and pass it what
  // it is expecting and allow it to do some of the object
  // initialization for us:
  Animal.prototype.constructor.call(this, gender);
  
  // Arguments meant for the current constructor are handled 
  // in the current constructor
  this.canFly = canFly
  
  // The inherited properties are available:
  console.log("Bird is a " + this.gender + " and it can fly: " + this.canFly);
}

// This just causes Bird to inherit from Animal. This alone
// doesn't cause the Animal constructor to fire when new Bird()
// is executed.
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

// By using a different prototype, we have wiped out the native
// constructor so we will reset just the contstructor so that
// constructions of Bird work properly
Bird.prototype.constructor = Bird;

// Just a test to show that making an Animal properly
// requires that the Animal constructor be called and
// passed a gender.
console.log("--- Creating New Animal ---");
var generic = new Animal("male");

// You are explicitly invoking the Bird constructor here.
// It's going to fire that function. That function, in turn,
// is configured to invoke the prototype object's constructor.
// The gender property will be handled by the Animal constructor
// and the canFly will be handled by the Bird constructor.
console.log("--- Creating New Bird ---");
duck = new Bird("female", false);

// ************************************************

function Falcon(gender, canFly, trained){
  // We'll pass the arguments needed by the parent object to it
  Bird.prototype.constructor.call(this, gender, canFly);
  
  // And set current instance properties right here
  this.trained = trained;

  console.log("Bird is a " + this.gender + ", can fly: " + this.canFly + " and is trained: " + this.trained);
}

Falcon.prototype = Object.create(Bird.prototype);

// By using a different prototype, we have wiped out the native
// constructor so we will reset just the contstructor so that
// constructions of Falcon work properly
Falcon.prototype.constructor = Falcon;

console.log("--- Creating New Falcon ---");
let f = new Falcon("female", true, false);
```

Comment: When you set the `Bird` prototype to `Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` what happens to `Bird.prototype.constructor`? If I want to make a class that inherits from `Bird` how do I call it's constructor?

Comment: @MarkMeyer When you set `Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`, it doesn't mean that when you invoke `Bird()` that `Animal()` will fire. It simply means that `Bird.prototype` now equals `Animal.prototype`. And, `Bird.prototype.constructor` now equals `Animal`. But, that's where you are getting confused. `Bird.prototype.constructor == Animal` (because `Bird.prototype` ***is*** `Animal`), not `Bird.constructor`. That is still `Bird`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When you subclass animal you do: `Animal.prototype.constructor.call(this, gender)` to set the super's instance variables like `gender`. Now lets say I want to make a `Falcon` class that inherits from `Bird` so in it's constructor I call `Bird.prototype.constructor.call(this, gender, true)` Does it set `canFly` to true on my Falcon instance? Easy to show in code: https://repl.it/@ak_mark/GroundedLastEvents The issue is the `Bird.prototype.constructor` no longer points to `Bird()`.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if I try to subclass `Bird` the same way `Bird` subclasses `Animal` it doesn't work. I'm doing exactly the same thing with Falcon in the repl.it; https://repl.it/@ak_mark/GroundedLastEvents What am I missing in the repl?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I see what you are saying. Yes, swapping the `prototype` does become an issue here and the solution is to manually correct the `prototype.constructor` after setting the prototype. This works because `Object.create()` make a **new, distinct instance** of the prototype object for the sub-object. Changing its constructor won't change it for the entire group - only for derived types. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: This may also help, see section 2.1 of [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/understanding-constructor-property/).

Comment: That's definitely one way to fix it. I would be more inclined to use the simpler: `Object.setPrototypeOf(Bird.prototype, Animal.prototype);` (despite the performance warnings) to chain the prototypes rather than nuke the Bird prototype. (or sweep it under the rug with es6 Classes).

Comment: @MarkMeyer both `Object.create()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()` were created to help automate the inheritance process and yes, that can work. I've been working with JavaScript for 20+ years (well before these methods existed) and find that it's still valuable to show and solve these issues the way I have as it exposes the real plumbing of the language.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
Bird.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

makes the prototype object of the `Bird` constructor be a *new* object whose own prototype is the `Animal` *prototype*, not the `Animal` constructor itself.

Thus

```
duck = new Bird()
```

makes a new object whose constructor is `Bird`, whose prototype is the `Bird` prototype, which in turn inherits from the `Animal` prototype.

This way, your `Animal` prototype could have a method called `eat()`, so a call to

```
duck.eat("fish")
```

would effectively be a call to the `eat()` method on the `Animal` prototype. Why? Well there's no "eat" property directly on the `duck` object, and none on the `Bird` prototype, but there *is* an "eat" property on the `Animal` prototype.